# jUnit fail() conventions

Tags: unit-testing, junit, conventions

I am wondering, by convention, when a test fails, is it appropriate to:

- Say why it failed (business logic)
- Say why the message is seen (exception should have been thrown and it's not)

For instance,

```
fail("Accessed the element which does not exist");
```

or

```
fail("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException was expected but something bad happened");
```

Which one is generally preferred/ accepted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that this is testing code and shouldn't make it into the final build, I'd say the more verbose the better. As such, I'd go with the first one - it's much clearer what the root cause of the problem is, which makes it easier to correct.

I'd avoid the second one under all circumstances because it's not very helpful for a tester, and if it does somehow make it into the final build its even more cryptic than the first to an end user - it simply is no help for testers or users alike.

The one other option that I'd consider is rather than indicating that an exception occurred, instead give details of the actual exception - that's why stack traces were invented. That would convey more detail than either method listed.

Answer (score 18):

First, if you expect the API you test to throw an exception, instead of doing a `try-catch` with a `fail()`...

```
@Test
public void testMe() {
   try {
      api.testThis();
      fail("should not reach here");
   }
   catch(MyException e) {}
}
```

... you should do this:-

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void testMe() {
   api.testThis();
}
```

That said, I rarely use `fail()`. If I need to perform certain validation and the condition fails, I will most likely use assertions than using `fail()`... for example:-

... instead of...

```
@Test
public void testMe() {
   boolean bool = api.testThis();
   if (!bool) {
      fail("should be true because bla bla bla");
   }
}
```

... do this:-

```
@Test
public void testMe() {
   boolean bool = api.testThis();
   assertTrue("bla bla bla",bool);
}
```

However, if you really need to use `fail()`, be verbose and explain why it fails rather than "should not reach here" or "should fail here" because that doesn't help folks who read the testcases.

Granted, these are just simple examples.... but I think I get my points across. :)

Comment: Hadn't seen the expected exception in the annotation syntax before. Neat.

Comment: Caveat on using the annotation: If your method can throw the exception with different error messages or more than one place, it will be better to use a try-catch and compare the error message. Look at this blog post for more details: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/20/use-junits-expected-exceptions-sparingly/

Answer (score 4):

If there *were* a convention about this I would ignore it.  You should say whatever will best communicate to someone seeing this message the nature of the problem in such a way that it can be resolved as easily as possible.  Too often adhering to a convention fails in this regard.

Comment: But if there is a convention that someone expects that is ignored, it can cause confusion. When you write a test, you don't know who might be looking at it in 10 years. Then again... in 10 years, maybe the convention has changed.